# Experiencing Segmentation Fault issue in C code on Windows machine only

Tags: c, windows, gcc, memory-management

I'm trying to pass the slice of the output of one function `slice` to another function, however I receive Segmentation fault error at line 93 in `append_2d_slice` slice function. I commented line which causes the problem. I suspect I'm passing `slice` variable to the function in a wrong way, but I'm not sure.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
//Works on Collab
void awe_2d_heterogeneous_8th_order_data_time_reverse(
    double** UUo, double** UUm, int nx, int ny, double dx, double dy,
    double dt, double** v, double** slice, int it, double rx
) {
    // Get dimensions of the wavefield
    int irx = (int)(rx / dx); // Force to be integer

    // Inject wavelet
    for (int i = 0; i < ny; i++) {
     //   printf("i: %d\n", i);
        UUo[irx][i] += dt * dt * slice[i][it];

    }

    // Define Courant numbers (squared)
    double dtdx2 = (dt / dx) * (dt / dx);
    double dtdy2 = (dt / dy) * (dt / dy);

    // Update solution
    for (int i = 4; i < nx - 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 4; j < ny - 4; j++) {
            UUm[i][j] = 2 * UUo[i][j] - UUm[i][j] + dtdx2 * v[i][j] * v[i][j] * (
                -1.0/560 * UUo[i - 4][j]
                + 8.0/315 * UUo[i - 3][j]
                - 1.0/5 * UUo[i - 2][j]
                + 8.0/5 * UUo[i - 1][j]
                - 205.0/72 * UUo[i][j]
                + 8.0/5 * UUo[i + 1][j]
                - 1.0/5 * UUo[i + 2][j]
                + 8.0/315 * UUo[i + 3][j]
                - 1.0/560 * UUo[i + 4][j]) + dtdy2 * v[i][j] * v[i][j] * (
                -1.0/560 * UUo[i][j - 4]
                + 8.0/315 * UUo[i][j - 3]
                - 1.0/5 * UUo[i][j - 2]
                + 8.0/5 * UUo[i][j - 1]
                - 205.0/72 * UUo[i][j]
                + 8.0/5 * UUo[i][j + 1]
                - 1.0/5 * UUo[i][j + 2]
                + 8.0/315 * UUo[i][j + 3]
                - 1.0/560 * UUo[i][j + 4]);
        }
    }
}

void awe_2d_explicit_solver_heterogeneous_8th_order(
    double** UUo, double** UUm, int nx, int ny, double dx, double dy,
    double dt, double** v, double* F, int it, double sx, double sy
) {
    // Define Courant numbers (squared)
    double dtdx2 = (dt / dx) * (dt / dx);
    double dtdy2 = (dt / dy) * (dt / dy);

    // Source location
    int isx = (int)(sx / dx);
    int isy = (int)(sy / dy);

    // Inject wavelet
    UUo[isx][isy] += dt * dt * F[it];

    // Update solution without using slicing
    for (int i = 4; i < nx - 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 4; j < ny - 4; j++) {
            UUm[i][j] = 2 * UUo[i][j] - UUm[i][j] + dtdx2 * v[i][j] * v[i][j] * (
                -1.0/560 * UUo[i - 4][j]
                + 8.0/315 * UUo[i - 3][j]
                - 1.0/5 * UUo[i - 2][j]
                + 8.0/5 * UUo[i - 1][j]
                - 205.0/72 * UUo[i][j]
                + 8.0/5 * UUo[i + 1][j]
                - 1.0/5 * UUo[i + 2][j]
                + 8.0/315 * UUo[i + 3][j]
                - 1.0/560 * UUo[i + 4][j]) + dtdy2 * v[i][j] * v[i][j] * (
                -1.0/560 * UUo[i][j - 4]
                + 8.0/315 * UUo[i][j - 3]
                - 1.0/5 * UUo[i][j - 2]
                + 8.0/5 * UUo[i][j - 1]
                - 205.0/72 * UUo[i][j]
                + 8.0/5 * UUo[i][j + 1]
                - 1.0/5 * UUo[i][j + 2]
                + 8.0/315 * UUo[i][j + 3]
                - 1.0/560 * UUo[i][j + 4]);
        }
    }
}

void append_2d_slice(double*** dest, double** src, int nx, int ny, int nt) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ny; j++) {
            dest[i][j][nt] = src[i][j]; // Debugger Points here Segmenation fault
        }
    }
}

void write_text_file_slice(double** slice, int nx, int ny, const char* filename) {
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "w");
    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file for writing.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Write slice data to the text file
    for (int i = 0; i < nx; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < ny; j++) {
            fprintf(file, "%.50lf ", slice[i][j]);
        }
        fprintf(file, "\n");
    }

    fclose(file);
}

int main() {
    // Define constants and arrays
    int nz = 300;
    int nx = 298;
    double dz = 5.0;
    double dx = 5.0;
    double t0 = 0.05;
    double CC = 0.5;
    int nt = 2000;
    double F[nt];
    double sx = 25;
    double sy = 800;

    // Initialize UUo and UUm with zeros
    double **UUo = malloc(nz * sizeof *UUo);
    double **UUm = malloc(nz * sizeof *UUm);
    double **UUo1 = malloc(nz * sizeof *UUo1);
    double **UUm1 = malloc(nz * sizeof *UUm1);
    double **v = malloc(nz * sizeof *v);

    for (int i = 0; i < nz; i++) {
        UUo[i] = calloc(nx, sizeof *UUo[i]);
        UUm[i] = calloc(nx, sizeof *UUm[i]);
        UUo1[i] = calloc(nx, sizeof *UUo1[i]);//addition
        UUm1[i] = calloc(nx, sizeof *UUm1[i]);//addition
        v[i] = calloc(nx, sizeof *v[i]);
    }

    // Initialize fff with zeros
    double ***fff = malloc(nz * sizeof *fff);
    for (int i = 0; i < nz; i++) {
        fff[i] = calloc(nx, sizeof *fff[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < nx; j++) {
            fff[i][j] = calloc(nt, sizeof *fff[i][j]);
        }
    }

    // Initialize mmm with zeros
    double ***mmm = malloc(nz * sizeof *mmm);
    for (int i = 0; i < nz; i++) {
        mmm[i] = calloc(nx, sizeof *mmm[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < nx; j++) {
            mmm[i][j] = calloc(nt, sizeof *mmm[i][j]);
        }
    }

    // Time stepping parameters
    double dt = CC * dz / 5560.328125; // Assuming 'v' is the maximum value
    double t[nt];
    for (int i = 0; i < nt; i++) {
        t[i] = i * dt;
    }

    // Define forcing function
    double ss = 0.01;
    for (int i = 0; i < nt; i++) {
        F[i] = (1.0 - ((t[i] - t0) / ss) * ((t[i] - t0) / ss)) * exp(-((t[i] - t0) * (t[i] - t0)) / (2 * ss * ss));
    }

    // Read 'v' from the file
    FILE *file = fopen("marmousi.txt", "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file.\n");
        perror("fopen");
        return 1; // Exit with an error code
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < nz; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nx; j++) {
            if (fscanf(file, "%lf", &v[i][j]) != 1) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error reading from file.\n");
                fclose(file);
                return 1; // Exit with an error code
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(file);
        
    printf("Forward Propagation...\n");

    for (int it = 0; it < nt; it++) {
        awe_2d_explicit_solver_heterogeneous_8th_order(UUo1, UUm1, nz, nx, dz, dx, dt, v, F, it, sx, sy);
        // Swap UUo and UUm
        double** tmp = UUo1;
        UUo1 = UUm1;
        UUm1 = tmp;
        append_2d_slice(fff, UUo1, nz, nx, it);
    }
    printf("Forward Propagation Done !\n");
    double** slice = fff[5];

    write_text_file_slice(slice, nx, nt, "slice.txt");
    
    printf("Backward Propagation...\n");
    for (int it = nt - 1; it > 0; it--) {
        //printf("%d\n",it);
        awe_2d_heterogeneous_8th_order_data_time_reverse(UUo, UUm, nz, nx, dz, dx, dt, v, slice, it, sx);
        double** tmp = UUo;
        UUo = UUm;
        UUm = tmp;
        append_2d_slice(mmm, UUo, nz, nx, nt - 1 - it);// When I uncomment this part the code stops working and  Debugger Points at line 93 on Windows Machine
    }
    printf("Backward Propagation Done !\n");
    double** slicep = mmm[5];
    write_text_file_slice(slicep, nx, nt, "slicep.txt"); 

    // Free allocated memory
    for (int i = 0; i < nz; i++) {
        free(UUo[i]);
        free(UUm[i]);
        free(UUo1[i]);
        free(UUm1[i]);
        free(v[i]);
    }
    free(UUo);
    free(UUm);
    free(UUo1);
    free(UUm1);
    free(v);

    for (int i = 0; i < nz; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nx; j++) {
            free(fff[i][j]);
            free(mmm[i][j]);
        }
        free(fff[i]);
        free(mmm[i]);
    }
    free(fff);
    free(mmm);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the link to txt file used in script : https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1pmSkKrxS7IWDGyPiyl0SuNEh3gidmyFS?usp=drive_link

Edit_0:

The code above with uncommented line `append_2d_slice(mmm, UUo, nz, nx, nt - 1 - it);` works on Colab and wsl (Windows Subsystem for Linux) , however it does not work on Windows . The question is Why ? Could it be version of gcc ?

gcc version on Windows : gcc.exe (MinGW.org GCC-6.3.0-1) 6.3.0
gcc version on Linux: gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.2) 9.4.0

Edit_1:
Okay, I configured runner so that code runs on WSL Terminal and it solves the issue, but I'm still not sure why it doesn't work on Windows I suspect version of gcc.

Comment: `double ***mmm` pointer to pointer to pointer, holy moley. Your variable naming is pretty bad which makes this super hard to even attempt at debugging by an outsider. Why not give the variables a more meaningful name. The code gets compiled to machine code so there is no overhead.

Comment: What do you mean by 'pointer to pointer to pointer' ? It is done to allocate space for 3D variable. Since I'm trying to append 2d slices ```UUo``` to it. The similar operation done to append `UUo1` slices to 3d ```fff``` variable.

Comment: After `printf("Backward Propagation...\n");` the line `double** tmp = UUo1;` looks wrong... Too much copy/paste code without pausing to shrink its volume...

Comment: `double *mmm` is a pointer to double, `double **mmm` is a pointer to a pointer to double, `double ***mmm` is a pointer to a pointer to a pointer to double. So when it comes to the memory allocation one needs to be very careful in such a deep level, and I think your variable naming and the copy/paste nature of the code is making it quite difficult to reason about.

Comment: [Three Star Programmer](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer): it's not a compliment.

Comment: Why did you tag this memory-leak if the issue is a segfault?  When I answered your last question there were no leaks :-)

Comment: @Fe2O3 you are right in that case after `printf("Backward Propagation...\n");` it has to be ```double** tmp = UUo;```, I have already edited it.

Comment: @AllanWind Hi, I was dealing with half of the code since it was causing the problem, when I'm try to use 2 functions in code it causes segfault again ;( .

Comment: My point, really, was to remove the memory-leaks tag.

Comment: @AllanWind Done.

Comment: Will agree with other comments that any code with `***` in it is a minefield. Most brains can't cope with that for any non-trivial code, including yours it seems. Make some structures (and/or typedefs) to make it easier.

Comment: One other suggestion, revise code so it demonstrate the segfault (instead of commenting it out).

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the segfault with the above modified with the call to `append_2d_slice()` so maybe @Fe2O3's suggestion was all that was needed?

Comment: @AlanWind With uncommented `append_2d_slice(mmm, UUo, nz, nx, nt - 1 - it);` ?  But I have already applied @Fe2O3's suggestion, changing `double** tmp = UUo1;` to `double** tmp = UUo;` . I still get an error.

Comment: @AllanWind weirdly the code runs without any problems on Colab without any issues, why it is not running on a locale machine ?

Comment: Yes. I would double check (as in copy the code above to your system; then diff) that it's identical code.  If we can't reproduce the issue it's hard to help you.  You already run the code the debugger so on the line it segfaults on what are `i`, `j`, and `nt`?  One of these are likely out of bounds.

Comment: @AllanWind I've checked with Diffchecker. The codes are same. If indexes are out of bound why the code executes without any issues on Colab ? Could it be related to the system specifications ?

Comment: If the code is the same then `append_2d_slice()` is still commented out.  If your code has undefined behavior (like out of bound access to arrays) then anything is possible.

Comment: In both test cases on my local machine and Colab `append_2d_slice(mmm, UUo, nz, nx, nt - 1 - it);` is not commented .

Comment: I understand but we can only see the above and it's commented out.  I asked you to compare the above with what you have.  You did something else which is ok but doesn't help us.

Comment: @AllanWind wdym ? I cross checked everything and the codes are same. The goal is to make the above code work with uncommented `append_2d_slice(mmm, UUo, nz, nx, nt - 1 - it);`.

Comment: The code above with uncommented line `append_2d_slice(mmm, UUo, nz, nx, nt - 1 - it);` works on Colab and wsl (Windows Subsystem for Linux) , however it does not work on Windows . The question is why ?

Comment: You have 3 copies of your code: a) stackoverflow, b) colab and c) wsl.  I asked you to compare a) with b).  You compared b) and c).  b) and c) is invisible to us.  I asked your earlier to fix a) so it's same as b) and c) which you haven't yet, so it's working code till you realize you have to change it to reproduce the issue, and as I mentioned earlier when I changed it I was not able to reproduce the issue.

Comment: If your question now is why your code behaves differently then you revise the question and tag the question with windows and probably tell what compiler you use.  I don't use windows so I can't help you.  I am not arguing with you just trying help revise the question so someone might be able to.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If someone else has similar issue, C code running without issues on Linux, WSL, Colab but not on Windows machine.Configure your code_runner so that it runs on WSL Terminal. In my case I'm using Visual Studio Code. I include here the [link](https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/issues/468#issuecomment-763017668.) which shows how to configure that on Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 0):

"*suspecting wrong passage of variable to function...*" Hard to tell in this morass of code. While copy/paste is an expedient solution when racing toward a finish line, like the "Tortoise and Hare" fable, expediency comes back to bite at its own discretion.

Below is a simplification (untested) of the newly spawned 2nd version of the heart of the processing. While it's true that pre-mature optimisation should be avoided, this rule-of-thumb must be tempered by realising when one is headed toward the pit of despair that is replicated functionality.

```
void run(
    double** UUo, double** UUm, double** v,
    int nx, int ny,
    double dx, double dy, double dt
) {
    // coefficients as array of constants.
    const double arr[] = { 205.0/72.0, 8.0/5.0, 1.0/5.0, 8.0/315.0, 1.0/560.0 };
    // Courant numbers (squared)
    const double dtdx2 = (dt / dx) * (dt / dx);
    const double dtdy2 = (dt / dy) * (dt / dy);

    for (int i = 4; i < nx - 4; i++)
        for (int j = 4; j < ny - 4; j++) {
            double someSqr = v[i][j] * v[i][j];
            UUm[i][j]
                = 2 * UUo[i][j] - UUm[i][j]
                + dtdx2 * someSqr * (
                    - arr[4] * UUo[i - 4][j]
                    + arr[3] * UUo[i - 3][j]
                    - arr[2] * UUo[i - 2][j]
                    + arr[1] * UUo[i - 1][j]
                    - arr[0] * UUo[i + 0][j]
                    + arr[1] * UUo[i + 1][j]
                    - arr[2] * UUo[i + 2][j]
                    + arr[3] * UUo[i + 3][j]
                    - arr[4] * UUo[i + 4][j] )
                + dtdy2 * someSqr * (
                    - arr[4] * UUo[i][j - 4]
                    + arr[3] * UUo[i][j - 3]
                    - arr[2] * UUo[i][j - 2]
                    + arr[1] * UUo[i][j - 1]
                    - arr[0] * UUo[i][j + 0]
                    + arr[1] * UUo[i][j + 1]
                    - arr[2] * UUo[i][j + 2]
                    + arr[3] * UUo[i][j + 3]
                    - arr[4] * UUo[i][j + 4] )
            ;
        }
}

// Preliminary processing for this version...
void awe_2d_heterogeneous_8th_order_data_time_reverse(
    double** UUo, double** UUm, int nx, int ny, double dx, double dy,
    double dt, double** v, double** slice, int it, double rx
) {
    // Get dimensions of the wavefield
    int irx = (int)(rx / dx); // Force to be integer

    // Inject wavelet
    for (int i = 0; i < ny; i++)
        UUo[irx][i] += dt * dt * slice[i][it];

    // Update solution
    run( UU0, UUm, v, nx, ny, dx, dy, dt );
}

// ... and preliminary processing for this version.
void awe_2d_explicit_solver_heterogeneous_8th_order(
    double** UUo, double** UUm, int nx, int ny, double dx, double dy,
    double dt, double** v, double* F, int it, double sx, double sy
) {
    // Source location
    int isx = (int)(sx / dx);
    int isy = (int)(sy / dy);

    // Inject wavelet
    UUo[isx][isy] += dt * dt * F[it];

    // Update solution without using slicing
    run( UU0, UUm, v, nx, ny, dx, dy, dt );
}
```

While this may or may not answer the OP's problem, this simplification at least opens the window to tracking down the problem much more simply. (The setting of a single element in the 2nd version does seem odd. Is there a missing loop?)